# Magento : How to override resource file?

Tags: php, mysql, magento, overriding

I want to create a magento module in which i need to override the file

```
app/code/core/Mage/Catalog/Model/Resource/Eav/Mysql4/Product/Attribute/Backend/Tierprice.php
```

I tried with the following code but i am getting the error `"Invalid backend model specified: catalog/product_attribute_backend_tierprice"`

```
 <catalog>
  <rewrite>
    <product_attribute_backend_tierprice>
      Module_Catalog_Model_Product_Attribute_Backend_Tierprice
    </product_attribute_backend_tierprice>
  </rewrite>
</catalog>

<catalog_resource>
  <class>Mage_Catalog_Model_Resource</class>
      <rewrite>
        <eav_mysql4_product_attribute_backend_tierprice>
            Module_Catalog_Model_Resource_Eav_Mysql4_Product_Attribute_Backend_Tierprice
        </eav_mysql4_product_attribute_backend_tierprice>
      </rewrite>                            
</catalog_resource>
```

I am using magento 1.9.

Please help .

Answer (score 0, accepted):

At last resolved it

```
         <models>
                <catalog>
                    <rewrite>
                        <product_type_price>Module_Catalog_Model_Product_Type_Price</product_type_price>
                        <product_attribute_backend_tierprice>Module_Catalog_Model_Product_Attribute_Backend_Tierprice</product_attribute_backend_tierprice>
                    </rewrite>
                </catalog> 
                <catalog_resource>
                    <class>Mage_Catalog_Model_Resource</class>
                    <deprecatedNode>catalog_resource_eav_mysql4</deprecatedNode>
                    <rewrite>
                        <product_attribute_backend_tierprice>Module_Catalog_Model_Resource_Eav_Mysql4_Product_Attribute_Backend_Tierprice</product_attribute_backend_tierprice>
                    </rewrite>                            
                </catalog_resource>
         </models>
```

Answer (score 0):

Try putting the rewrites in one line like so:

```
<catalog>
    <rewrite>
        <product_attribute_backend_tierprice>Module_Catalog_Model_Product_Attribute_Backend_Tierprice</product_attribute_backend_tierprice>
    </rewrite>
</catalog>

<catalog_resource>
    <class>Mage_Catalog_Model_Resource</class>
    <rewrite>
        <eav_mysql4_product_attribute_backend_tierprice>Module_Catalog_Model_Resource_Eav_Mysql4_Product_Attribute_Backend_Tierprice</eav_mysql4_product_attribute_backend_tierprice>
    </rewrite>                            
</catalog_resource>
```

Magento doesn't like newlines in config files (at least in some cases).